# How to pipe STDIN to a PHP-spawned proc?

Tags: php, stdin, proc

To my PHPeoples,

This is sort of a weird PHPuzzle, but I'm wondering if it's PHPossible.

The end goal is the equivalent functionality of

```
mysql mydb < file.sql
```

But with an API like this

```
./restore < file.sql
```

Where `restore` is a PHP script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env php

$cmd = "msyql mydb";
passthru($cmd, $status);
```

However, I want to pass STDIN to the `passthru` command.

The clear benefit here is that I can put `restore` somewhere in a pipeline and everything works peachy. Here's an example

```
# would be pretty awesome!
ssh $remote "msyqldump $config mydb | gzip" | gzip -dc | ./restore
```

Anyway, I doubt it's possible using `passthru`, but perhaps with `proc_open` in some way?

---

As a last case resort, in the event of an unsolvable PHPredicament, I would do something like this

```
./restore file.sql
```

With script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env php

$cmd = sprintf("mysql mydb < %s", $argv[1]);
passthru($cmd, $status);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What! PHProfound!

Turns out `passthru` already does this! PHenomenalP!

Check it out, PHPals:

**gzip.php**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

passthru("gzip", $status);

if ($status !== 0) {
  error_log("gzip exited with status %d", $status);
}
```

How PHProgressivist!

```
echo "hello" | php gzip.php | gzip -dc
```

Output

```
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

PHPwnd

**./restore**

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

// set descriptors
$desc = array(
  0 => array("file", "php://stdin", "r"),
  1 => array("pipe", "w"),
  2 => array("pipe", "w")
);

// open child proc
$proc = proc_open("mysql -uUSER -pPASS mydb", $desc, $pipes);

if (is_resource($proc)) {

  // display child proc stdout
  echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);

  // close file streams
  array_map('fclose', $pipes);

  // get return value
  $ret = proc_close($proc);

  // display return value
  printf("command returned %s\n", $ret);
}
```

Example use

```sh
cat file.sql.gz | gzip -dc | ./restore
```